# Calculate possible combinations in C

Tags: c

I've started studying C and I'm trying to practice it developing a small application. Please, could you give any tips about what to do here?

I want to buy shoes from three different brands (brandA=50; brandB=100; brandC=150). I need to spend 2000 dollars on it and buy exactly 20 shoes.

How could I write a program to display all possible combinations?

E.g. brandA (10 shoes), brandB (0 shoe), brandC(10 shoes);
brandA(1 shoe), brandB (3 shoes), brandC (11 shoes), etc.

Please, I don't want the full code now but tips about how to do it.

I really appreciate any help. Tks!

**I've updated my post to include a code. Does this code make any sense?**

```
int main(void) {

int brandA=50, brandB=100, brandC=150, ba, bb, bc;

for(ba=0;ba<=20;ba++) {
    for(bb=0;bb<=20;bb++) {
        for(bc=0;bc<=20;bc++) {
            if(ba+bb+bc==20 && (ba*brandA)+(bb*brandB)+(bc*brandC)==2000 {
                printf("You can buy %d brandA, %d brandB, %d brandC", ba,bb,bc);   
            }
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Make an attempt and we will help you from there.

Comment: Start off with `int main(void){ return 0; }`  Then, use your imagination along with a good C programming book, or Google.  If you show some effort, you will get a better response.

Comment: ...and you code until now, look like ??

Comment: Hi @JackV actually, I'm not sure about how to start. I've thought about using a for loop to calculate the possible combinations to match the budget (2000) and, then, another for loop to match which of those combinations also have exactly 20 shoes. But I'm not sure about how to start and if it's the best approach. Tks!

Comment: @J.Parker See you have some idea as to how to start  so why dont you start with that and then post it so you have at least some code for us to help you with.  Also since you are a beginner i wouldnt be too worried to if its the "Best approach" for now just do it how you think you should and as you get more experienced you can focus on optimization

Comment: If you'd like to do crazy stuff: [Using Monads in C++ to solve constraints](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/05/11/using-monads-in-c-to-solve-constraints-1-the-list-monad/) (for C++ only, 'unfortunately' :P)

Comment: Worst case scenario, you can always start with the 'brute force' method and just calculate the cost and number of shoes you can buy for every combination (only selecting when the combination is 20 and the cost 2000). The inartful `for (A=0;A<40;A++) for (B=0;B<20;B++) for (C=0; C<14;C++) {test cost; test quantity}`. Then you could refine your logic a bit.

Comment: @JackV I've updated my post to include a code but I don't know if that code makes any sense. :(

Comment: Did you run it?  Looks like you got it.

Comment: @dbush it worked! Thanks a lot everybody who helped me! :)

Answer (score 0):

For first you have to have an algorithm...

1. Take all zero shoes brandA=0; brandB=0; brandC=0
2. Check total quantity= 0+0+0 = 0
3. If it is not 20 pcs - pass it
4. If it equal 20 pcs ( for example: brandA=5; brandB=5; brandC=10) - check total price.
5. If total price equal 2000 - show it, if not - pass it.
6. Increment brandA value till 20
7. repeat steps 2-6
8. Increment brandB value till 20
9. repeat steps 2-8
10. Increment brandC value till 20
11. repeat steps 2-10

Note: you can use 3 included 'for'  cycles :)

Comment: You don't need the innermost loop, because `c = 20 - a - b`. Two nested loops should be enough for your approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner I suggest to start with backtracking and recursion.

Even if backtracking is a costly technique it's great for a beginner to see how recursion can provide a simple yet powerful solution to a problem.

Here are some resources for you to start: http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/course/cis680/cis680Ch19.html

And if you are serious about programming you should also read some books about algorithms and data structures since you will rely heavily on these basic fundamentals:
1. [The Algorithm Design Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849967202) 
2. The Pragmatic Programmer: From Journeyman to Master

Comment: I got it! But thanks for the reading tips. I'll surely take a look on it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have it working, I feel no guilt in suggesting a potential refinement. Rather than a pure brute force triple loop, as others have mentioned, you can use the relationship between `A`, `B` & `C` to eliminate the third loop. Remember in C, there are generally many ways to approach any given problem and many ways to handle the output. As long as the logic and syntax are correct, then the only difference will be in the efficiency of the algorithms. Here is an example of eliminating the third loop:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int ca = 50;
    int cb = 100;
    int cc = 150;
    int budget = 2000;
    int pairs = 20;
    int a, b, c, cost;

    for (a = 0; a < budget/ca; a++)
        for (b = 0; b < budget/cb; b++)
        {
            c = pairs - (a + b);
            if ((cost = a * ca + b * cb + c * cc) != budget)
                continue;

            printf ("\n a (%2d) * %3d = %4d"
                    "\n b (%2d) * %3d = %4d"
                    "\n c (%2d) * %3d = %4d\n",
                    a, ca, a * ca, b, cb, b * cb, c, cc, c * cc);
            printf (" ===================\n   (%d)         %d\n", pairs, budget);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

**Compiling**

Since you are new to C, when you compile your code, make sure you **always** compile with **warnings enabled**. The compiler warnings are there for a reason, and there are very, very few circumstances where you can rely on code that doesn't compile **without** warnings. At minimum, you will want to compile with `-Wall -Wextra` enabled (gcc). You can also include `-pedantic` if you want to check your code against virtually all possible warnings. For example, to compile the code above:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o bin/shoes shoes.c
```

If you want to add optimizations to the fullest extent, you can add:

```
 -Ofast  (-03 with gcc < 4.6)
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/shoes

 a ( 1) *  50 =   50
 b (18) * 100 = 1800
 c ( 1) * 150 =  150
 ===================
   (20)         2000

 a ( 2) *  50 =  100
 b (16) * 100 = 1600
 c ( 2) * 150 =  300
 ===================
   (20)         2000

 a ( 3) *  50 =  150
 b (14) * 100 = 1400
 c ( 3) * 150 =  450
 ===================
   (20)         2000

 <..snip..>

 a ( 9) *  50 =  450
 b ( 2) * 100 =  200
 c ( 9) * 150 = 1350
 ===================
   (20)         2000

 a (10) *  50 =  500
 b ( 0) * 100 =    0
 c (10) * 150 = 1500
 ===================
   (20)         2000
```

Good luck learning C. There is no other comparable language that gives you the precise low-level control that you have in C. (assembler excluded) But that precise control doesn't come for free. There is a learning curve involved and there is a bit more to cover in C before you will lose that "fish out of water" feeling and feel comfortable with the language. The benefit of learning C, with the low-level access it provides, is it will greatly improve your understanding of how programming works. That knowledge is applicable to all other programming languages (no matter how hard the other languages work to hide the details from you). C is time well spent.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful.

Comment: Who knows, you may be the next Linus, I'm just doing my part to help you along the way...